# Variables Timed out during debugging in Jetbrains Rider or Visual Studio

Tags: c#, debugging, rider

I try to debug my Selenium UI-Tests and when I want to see Details of a variable I always get a Timed Out within 1000 ms. I know I can put the time up, but why is the debugger or the CLR so slow to evaluate the details of a variable?

Can anyone explain this to me?

[image]

Comment: I put the time up to 10000ms but also a timed out

Comment: same problem, no ideas sadly :(

Comment: I reported this to jetbrains and they opened a ticket https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-33716

Comment: Thanks. I've raised some debugger bugs and none of them have been fixed. Can you maybe add a #rider tag to the question? Might help Jetbrains find things here.